# Induction question

Tags: induction

I have this homework question in Proofs by Mathematical Induction and I don't have a clue how to resolve it, is there anyone that can help me?

When you roll a die you have $6$ possible outcomes $1,2,\ldots,6$. When you roll two dice you have $11$ possible outcomes $2,3,\ldots,12$  and when you roll three dice the possible outcome is 16. Use basic and inductive steps to show when $n\ge 1$ dice are rolled then the possible outcome is $5n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The induction hypothesis is

> When you roll $n$ dice, you can get any outcome from $n$ to $6n$.

**Hint:** There are $6n - n + 1 $ integers between $n$ and $6n$ inclusive.

Comment: An induction hypothesis would never start with "Show that".

Comment: @MichaelHardy Point taken.